# Adding attachment to JIRA issue using the REST API and Qt with QNetworkRequest

Tags: c++, qt, rest, jira, jira-rest-api

I'm trying to add an attacment to an existing JIRA issue using the REST API and Qt.

When I run the code below, the reply is an empty array ("[]").

**edit: updated the code**

```
QString APIhandler::attachFile(QString fileloc, QString issueKey, QString cookie)
{

//create multiPart
QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);

QFile *file = new QFile(fileloc);
//create httpPart for file
QHttpPart filePart;

filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/octet-stream"));
filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+ file->fileName()+ "\""));



file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); 
filePart.setBodyDevice(file);

file->setParent(multiPart);

multiPart->append(filePart);

QNetworkAccessManager *mngr = new QNetworkAccessManager();

QUrl issurl(baseURL + "/api/2/issue/"+ issueKey + "/attachments");

QNetworkRequest req(issurl);
QNetworkReply *reply ;

QEventLoop loop;

//add headers
req.setRawHeader("cookie", "JSESSIONID = " + cookie.toUtf8()); // the session cookie
req.setRawHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
req.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data; boundary=------------------------53a5a2cd1d9c8b7f");
//req.setRawHeader("Content-Length", postDataSize);

reply = mngr->post(req, multiPart);
multiPart->setParent(reply);
QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

loop.exec();


return reply->readAll();

}
```

[I am using the JIRA REST API documentation](https://docs.atlassian.com/jira/REST/latest/#d2e4287) and [qt documentation](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qhttpmultipart.html) for reference, and looking off of [this](https://answers.atlassian.com/questions/249347/how-do-i-upload-attachment-to-jira-issue-via-rest-api) java implementation (which I've tried to replicate).

It seems like I'm either missing a header, or adding the file incorrectly.

Any help is greatly appreciated!

**EDIT - Here's part of a wireshark comparing the example from the api using curl (LEFT) , and my code (RIGHT). The one on the left works, and clearly has different MIME data, but I'm not sure how to implement that in Qt**

[image]

Comment: Do you have access to a working system that is using the REST API? If so, you could grab a Wireshark trace of the working system adding an attachment and compare against a Wireshark trace of your API call.

Comment: @DavidLaPorte - I don't unfortunately.

Comment: If you don't, how can you test this code?

Comment: Did you try using `curl` as noted in the API docs? `curl -D- -u admin:admin -X POST -H "X-Atlassian-Token: nocheck" -F "file=@myfile.txt" http://myhost/rest/api/2/issue/TEST-123/attachments` and get a Wireshark trace from that vs. your code?

Comment: @Koshinae I have access to a working server to submit the files and JIRA issue to, but using the normal webpage to add an attachment doesn't appear to use the api.

Comment: @DavidLaPorte I've updated the original post with part of the wireshark comparing the cUrl request and the request from my code. I'm not all that familiar with wireshark, but the MIME data each request is submitting seemed to be the main difference.

Comment: On the `filePart` set the content type header (`QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader`), let's see if that is the only thing missing.

Comment: I've put the revised code in the original post. Unfortunately the wireshark trace looks the same.

Comment: I should add that I've verified that I have the correct permissions and the statusCode of the reply is 200.

Comment: Any other ideas, @Koshinae?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Okay, so I figured it out. I might be the only one on earth who is using (or will use) Qt to interact with the JIRA API, but for posterity, here's what I came up with:

```
QString APIhandler::attachFile(QString fileloc, QString issueKey, QString cookie)
{

    QHttpMultiPart *multiPart = new QHttpMultiPart(QHttpMultiPart::FormDataType);
    QHttpPart filePart;
    QFileInfo fileInfo(fileloc);

    //what I wasn't doing before!
    multiPart->setBoundary("------------------------53a5a2cf4d9c8b7f");

    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentDispositionHeader, QVariant("form-data; name=\"file\"; filename=\""+fileInfo.fileName() +"\""));
    filePart.setHeader(QNetworkRequest::ContentTypeHeader, QVariant("application/octet-stream"));

    QFile *file = new QFile(fileloc);
    file->open(QIODevice::ReadOnly); 
    filePart.setBodyDevice(file);

    file->setParent(multiPart);
    multiPart->append(filePart);

    QNetworkAccessManager *mngr = new QNetworkAccessManager();

    QUrl issurl(baseURL + "/api/2/issue/"+ issueKey + "/attachments");

    QNetworkRequest req(issurl);
    QNetworkReply *reply ;

    QEventLoop loop;

    //add headers
    req.setRawHeader("X-Atlassian-Token", "nocheck");
    req.setRawHeader("cookie", "JSESSIONID = " + cookie.toUtf8()); // the session cookie
    req.setRawHeader("Content-Type", "multipart/form-data;boundary=------------------------53a5a2cf4d9c8b7f");

    reply = mngr->post(req, multiPart);
    multiPart->setParent(reply);
    QObject::connect(reply, SIGNAL(finished()), &loop, SLOT(quit()));

    loop.exec();

    //read the reply
    QByteArray bytes=reply->readAll();

    //return the reply JSON 
    return QString::fromUtf8(bytes.data(), bytes.size());

    delete file;
    delete multiPart;
    delete reply;
    delete mngr;

}
```

The key part here, and what I was doing wrong, was the way in which I set the boundary for the multipart. Instead of setting it in the header, I should have used:

`multipart->setBoundary()`

Which you can see reflected above.

If you're coming across this and are going to use it, I'd recommend cleaning it up a bit, first. But it works!